# How to draw a line from 2 mouse points and an angle using mouseMoved

Tags: java, swing, awt

when I move the mouse I want to draw a line at the direction where the mouse is going, but I have no idea how to do so. I keep getting a line that rotates at random directions with random length when moving the mouse.( It should start drawing the moment I run the program and mouse points are taken at mouseMoved)

Comment: How do you tell your line to start drawing? How do you tell your line to stop drawing?

Comment: @SaviourSelf the moment I run the program I want it to draw a line if I move, so if I move right then it should draw a line to the right, and so on with all directions

Comment: and the line never terminates?

Comment: @SaviourSelf when I change direction and the new line is drawn ill call repaint, so the new line is drawn and the old one wont be drawn.

Comment: If this is the case, using my example, you'll just have to change the `origX` and `origY` variables to reset the origin of the line once the condition to draw a new line is met.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using `mouseDragged`. The difference between `mouseMoved` and `mouseDragged` is that a when a mouseButton is clicked, it `mouseMoved` is disabled, and `mouseDragged` takes over.

I'm not sure how you tell your application to start drawing a line, so I used a `mouseClick` and `mouseDragged` to produce an example that you can modify to resolve your issue.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Angle extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    boolean pressed = false;
    int origX, origY;
    int currX, currY;
    JPanel p;

    public Angle()
    {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Mouse pressed");
        pressed = true;
        origX = arg0.getX();
        origY = arg0.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(origX, origY, currX, currY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        pressed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (pressed)
        {
            currX = arg0.getX();
            currY = arg0.getY();
            repaint();
            System.out.println(getAngle());
        }
    }

    public double getAngle()
    {
        double xDiff = origX - currX; 
        double yDiff = origY - currY;
        return 180 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {  }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.add(new Angle());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Example output]

EDIT: Update with mouseMoved instead.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Angle extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    boolean origSet = false;
    int origX, origY;
    int currX, currY;
    JPanel p;

    public Angle()
    {
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(origX, origY, currX, currY);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) { }

    public double getAngle()
    {
        double xDiff = origX - currX; 
        double yDiff = origY - currY;
        return 180 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (!origSet)
        {
            origX = arg0.getX();
            origY = arg0.getY();
            origSet = true;
        }
        currX = arg0.getX();
        currY = arg0.getY();
        repaint();
        System.out.println(getAngle());
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {  }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.add(new Angle());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot man, but the problem is that I have to use only MouseMoved. no clicking at all.

Comment: @Sherif This can be modified to use `mouseMoved`. Need a few minutes.

Comment: nope still not it, I still click to change the line. look, given 2 mouse points and an angle, draw a line with a certain length and width ( usually screen size ), the purpose of the 2 points is that if you have them you can construct  a line, and the angle provides direction.

Comment: @Sherif Clicking to change the line was removed when I edited the code out of the `mousePressed` method.

Comment: you solved the pressing thing, but ended up with a fixed starting point which is not what i need, also the line should be drawn with a fixed length. in your example if the starting point is lets say 0,0 and the end point was 5,5, then the line would be drawn from 0,0 to 5,5, what i want is if the starting point is 0,0 and end point is 5,5 then the line should be drawn till the end of the screen, lets say 100,100